# Run and Debug problems in Visual Studio Code using haxe

Tags: visual-studio-code, haxe, hashlink

I'm currently coding in Haxe with Heaps using Visual Studio Code. The latter has recently updated to version 1.56 which is now giving my a strange problem I can't manage to fix. Before the update, I was able to click Run and Debug using Hashlink in order to open the window of my game. After the update, when I Run and Debug it no longer opens the window, despite the compile.hxml and launch.json being exactly the same as before:

compile.hxml:

```
-cp src
-lib heaps
-lib hlsdl
-hl main.hl
-main Main
```

.json

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "HashLink (launch)",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "hl",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "preLaunchTask": {
            "type": "haxe",
            "args": "active configuration"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "HashLink (attach)",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": 6112,
        "type": "hl",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "preLaunchTask": {
            "type": "haxe",
            "args": "active configuration"
        }
    }
]
```

Is anyone experiencing a similar problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** hashlink-debugger 1.1.2 was released, which should fix the problem.

---

It's a known issue:

[HL debugger no longer works in latest vscode #97](https://github.com/vshaxe/hashlink-debugger/issues/97)

You can downgrade to the previous VSCode release or subscribe to the issue and wait for the hashlink-debugger update.

Comment: Cheers! I confirm that the new update does fix the problem. Thank you very much!